# How do we redirect a user from one page to another in ember.js?

Tags: javascript, ember.js

I was trying to find if ember.js has some or the other way we can redirect from one app page to another while maintaining some state data, like active routes.
(Not a single page app)

I'm in app A, route 3.

Now I'd like to redirect to another page, that contains app B.

I'd also like to maintain info, informing app B, that I am comming specifically from route 3, in app A.

Hope that makes some things clear.

Comment: http://emberjs.com/guides/routing/ is this wat u are looking for?

Comment: I think you might want to flesh out your question a bit more. It is quite vague.

Comment: Some more details added.

Comment: It looks like you are splitting your application into multiple Ember Application, and when you want to go from one application route to another application route why dont you let the server handle the switching pass params if needed ?

Comment: Okay, I get it. I'll simply use query params, and use javascript redirection.